# Cannot display data in ReactJS. Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to displaying data from my backend, but I'm getting error:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, price, descr, link, sqf}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I've been searching for solution and I came across .map but it doesn't work throws again an error.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ArticleService from '../services/articles';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    ArticleService.articles().then(
      (response) => {
        setContent(response.data);
      },
      (error) => {
        const _content =
          (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString();

        setContent(_content);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  console.log(content);
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h3>{content}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

console.log of content looks like this:
[image: console.log]

As you can see, I get content regularly I just can't display it on dashboard page.
When I try `{content.price}` it removes an error but still doesn't show nothing.
Any solutions???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your log, `content` is an array of objects so you want to map the array to valid JSX, for example if you want to render in a `div` element:

```
<div className="container">
  <h3>
    {content?.map((item) => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <div>{item.price}</div>
        <div>{item.descr}</div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </h3>
</div>
```

In addition, the initial state should be an empty array: `useState([])` to match the expected data:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
  ...
};
```

Comment: then i'm getting ×
TypeError: content.map is not a function which points to content.map line of code

Comment: `content` is undefined on first render as you need to fetch it, u can try `content && content.map(...)` or as in the answer `content?.map(...)`

Comment: yeah it works when i add content && before content.map ! Thanks dude <3

Comment: also one question what if i want to display whole object not just some item(not just .price)?

Comment: Just decide how to structure its JSX, you have the `item` object already, Ive added an example with showing the `descr` too

Comment: ummm it doesn't show desc it shows only price. Also when I try to get something else I cant get it, I only get blank page? EDIT: my mistake, wrong declaring variable.

Comment: No one can't guess why its not working, try making an example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-t80qj).